# Where should I put a common code in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have an application with Reactjs and Redux. There is an `action` which resets the state of the reducers. My question is: where is the best place to perform that? I am considering two options:

- each reducer handle the action and resets its state

  ```
  const reducer1 = (state = defaultState, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {
     case 'reset': {
       // ...
      }
      // ...
  }
  ```
- the root reducer resets the global state

  ```
  const appReducer = combineReducers({
      reducer1,
      reducer2,
      reducer3 
  })

  const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
      if ( (action.type === 'reset') ) {
          state = {}
       }

       return appReducer(state, action)
   }
  ```

Comment: Set the state as undefined instead of an empty object in your if statement for approach two. It will reset your different reducers to their initial state.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to have an action for reseting each reducer, this helps for extensibility in the future. Dispatch the clearState action, but do not set an empty object. Set it to the initial state, because if you put an empty object you can introduce bugs

Comment: You can't reset a reducer since a reducer is a function that performs a change in the state of an application. You can reset the state, not the reducer. The second part of the initial state is very right

Comment: @HuLuViCa, you are right, but each reducer has a particular state attached to it and usually in most projects when we want to take something from the state we query it like - state.testSessionReducer.something. That is why I said it like that. But good point, it could be confusing for beginners

Comment: Not necessarily, it some changes in the state of an application are broader and cover the scope of several unit reducers, and since reducers are clean (meaning you cannot dispatch another action from a reducer), you have to change several state unit from one single reducer.

Comment: Yes, but if you do that you will fire one action and catch it with the reducers you desire. The reducers that catch the action will change their own state, so I think its not a mistake to say that it changes its own state

Answer (score 0):

The first thing we must have clear is that reducers don't have states, stores have states, so you shouldn't say "the state of the reducer".

A reducer is a function that performs some change in the state of a store, and there is no specific limitation in the scope of such change, besides the scope of the store, so many reducers have overlapping scopes over the state of the store.

After that, I see no reason why you can not reset the whole state of the store with a single reducer, and when you need to make other changes with different scope, you can create other reducers to manage it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about the "state of the reducer". You are totally right, thanks!